# trouble with the division of two floats C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, division

I'm having problems with dividing two float values that appears to be a simple process.

http://imgur.com/EZz5Q1Z

the floats l and larg have the values of 20 and 10, which should result in a n1 value of 2. That's not the case though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post images; post the text output directly.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, in this case the image was instrumental in determining the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your breakpoint on the line containing the division, which means the debugger is showing the value of the variable *before* the division takes place. Step to the next instruction to see the correct value.